# How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when compiling Appcelerator Android app?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I try to compile apk using Appcelerator but i get this error. How to solve it.

Currently I'm using Titanium sdk: 5.2.0.GA

```
    >Error:
    >ERROR :  Failed to run dexer:
    >ERROR :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    >ERROR :  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Other error

> [ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
>   [ERROR] :
>   [ERROR] :  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
>   [ERROR] :  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   [ERROR] :      at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
>   [ERROR] :      at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:279)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>   [ERROR] :      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Hi again,
I get the solution from the link and the code is :

> ```
>    <property name="android.javac.maxmemory" type="string">1024M</property>
>    <property name="android.dx.maxmemory" type="string">2048M</property>
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Pl mention what you have tried to resolve this. Looks like out of memory exception.

Comment: Yes. I already find the solution for this problem. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: link for the solution : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19315

Comment: @afiz that link seems to be a bug report, and I don't see a solution or workaround. If you have a solution, could you add this as an answer to your own question that you can accept so others see the question has been resolved as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing something wrong in your code. And setting a larger `maxmemory` or large heap size is not the correct fix. Such solutions won't work on all devices and Android versions. You're *requesting* more memory but there's nothing that requires the OS to grant it to your app.

You've got a [memory leak](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/) or you're just unnecessarily using memory creating objects in inefficient ways. Re-examine your app's structure to optimize it rather than band-aiding it with a manifest setting.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator cannot handle too many javascript files when building for android.

i had 128 controllers & 188 views files. i deleted all unused files. Now i have 35 controllers & 56 views files, this successfully build on android.